# What's the best schema.org type to use to describe weekly yoga classes?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

The page https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk describes two yoga classes, that run every week.

Is an `Event` with a `potentialAction` of type `ExerciseAction` the best way to represent the classes?

Note these are classes that take place in various locations (e.g. church halls) so `HealthClub` didn't seem an appropriate type.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "hello YOGA",
      "startDate": "2018-06-13T19:45",
      "endDate": "2018-06-13T20:45",
      "description":
        "Yoga class at Friends Meeting House (Harrogate) every Thursday.",
      "image": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk/yoga-people.svg",
      "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "Friends Meeting House",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "12A Queens Parade",
          "addressLocality": "Harrogate",
          "addressRegion": "North Yorkshire",
          "postalCode": "HG1 5PP",
          "addressCountry": "GB"
        }
      },
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/LimitedAvailability",
        "price": "7.00",
        "priceCurrency": "GBP",
        "validFrom": "2018-05-01T12:00",
        "url": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk"
      },
      "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "ExerciseAction",
        "name": "hello YOGA",
        "description": "Small, friendly yoga class. Suitable for all abilities.",
        "exerciseType": "Yoga",
        "startTime": "2018-06-13T19:45",
        "endTime": "2018-06-13T20:45",
        "location": {
          "name": "Friends Meeting House",
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "12A Queens Parade",
          "addressLocality": "Harrogate",
          "addressRegion": "North Yorkshire",
          "postalCode": "HG1 5PP",
          "addressCountry": "GB"
        }
      },
      "performer": {
        "@type": "LocalBusiness",
        "description":
          "Small, friendly yoga classes. Suitable for all abilities. Strengthen body, increase flexibility and calm the mind.",
        "name": "hello YOGA",
        "email": "clare@hello-yoga.co.uk",
        "url": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk",
        "priceRange": "£7",
        "image": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk/yoga-people.svg",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "addressLocality": "Harrogate",
          "addressRegion": "North Yorkshire",
          "addressCountry": "GB"
        }
      }
    }
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "hello YOGA",
      "startDate": "2018-06-07T19:00",
      "endDate": "2018-06-07T20:00",
      "description":
        "Yoga class at Beckwith Health Club (Harrogate) every Wednesday.",
      "image": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk/yoga-people.svg",
      "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "Beckwith Health Club",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "Beckwith Health Club",
          "addressLocality": "Harrogate",
          "addressRegion": "North Yorkshire",
          "postalCode": "HG3 1UF",
          "addressCountry": "GB"
        }
      },
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/LimitedAvailability",
        "price": "7.00",
        "priceCurrency": "GBP",
        "validFrom": "2018-05-01T12:00",
        "url": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk"
      },
      "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "ExerciseAction",
        "name": "hello YOGA",
        "description": "Small, friendly yoga class. Suitable for all abilities.",
        "exerciseType": "Yoga",
        "startTime": "2018-06-07T19:00",
        "endTime": "2018-06-07T20:00",
        "location": {
          "name": "Beckwith Health Club",
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "Beckwith Health Club",
          "addressLocality": "Harrogate",
          "addressRegion": "North Yorkshire",
          "postalCode": "HG3 1UF",
          "addressCountry": "GB"
        }
      },
      "performer": {
        "@type": "LocalBusiness",
        "description":
          "Small, friendly yoga classes. Suitable for all abilities. Strengthen body, increase flexibility and calm the mind.",
        "name": "hello YOGA",
        "email": "clare@hello-yoga.co.uk",
        "url": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk",
        "priceRange": "£7",
        "image": "https://www.hello-yoga.co.uk/yoga-people.svg",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "addressLocality": "Harrogate",
          "addressRegion": "North Yorkshire",
          "addressCountry": "GB"
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Probably `http://schema.org/Course`

Comment: Thanks. I don't think `Course` is correct because weekly yoga classes don't make up a curriculum and don't have an explicit educational outcome of knowledge.

I think `Schedule` is probably my best bet but it's currently pending - https://pending.schema.org/Schedule